# i create functions.php in plugin files but add_action ('wp_head', 'function_name') don't work

Tags: plugins, actions, wp-head

ı use add_action hook in my plugin but not working hook

```
 add_action('wp_head', 'cerezcss');
        function cerezcss(){
        ?>
        <!--cerezcssbaslangic-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.pentayazilim.net/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pentacerez/admin/css/cerez.css">
        <!--cerezcssbitis-->
        <?php
        };
```

Comment: That’s not how plugins work. Please see the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/

Comment: thank you for your help